# Why decrement a shell variable as the side-effect of an unused argument?

Tags: bash

When trying to debug some networking code recently, I came across a retry loop, show in a cut-down form below:

```
while [ ${DELAY} -gt 0 ] ; do
    doSomething
    sleep 1
    : $((DELAY -= 1))
done
```

Now I get *what* it's doing, I'm just not sure *why* it's doing it that way. The `bash-builtins` `man` page states:

> `: [arguments]` No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any specified redirections.

Since you can simply modify the variable in `bash` with just `((DELAY -= 1))`, why is it doing that as a *side-effect* of giving the result to the `:` command, which evaluates but doesn't use it?

Comment: Is `set -e` involved?

Comment: If I had to make an educated guess, that is done to maintain POSIX compliance. POSIX provides [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) of `$((expression))` but makes no mention of `((expression)). So by using the `':'` to discard the result, you insure POSIX portability.

Comment: @melpomene, not in that script but it's set in the scripts that *call* it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Since `[[` isn't available in posix shell, posix compatibility can't be the reason.

Comment: @paxdiablo This can't get answered, we can only guess. Maybe the author didn't know that they can just `((delay-1))`? Ask them! :)

Comment: Sorry, @DavidC.Rankin, went back and checked, it was *indeed* a single `[` - will fix.

Comment: @hek2mgl, I'm not looking for a *definitive* answer why it *was* done, just a viable, sane one as to why it *could* have been done :-) There may well be a viable reason why you would do that, that someone other than the author would know. Hopefully, someone here will have it.

Comment: I would still try to contact the package author / maintainer. What piece of software are we talking about?

Comment: @hek2mgl: `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wait_iface`, which I suspect is part of `ifplugd`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174767/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-paxdiablo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually has to do with automated error handling. Because the script that calls this code is running under `set -e`, it will exit immediately on error.

You can see the effect with the following script:

```
set -e
DELAY=10
while [ ${DELAY} -gt 0 ] ; do
    echo Delaying $DELAY
    ((DELAY -= 1))
done
echo Finishing
```

With that script, you never *see* the `Finishing` line because the "exit code of `((DELAY -= 1))` is `0` normally, but `1` when the value drops to zero. This means that that the `set -e` in operation will stop the script at that point.

Using `: $((DELAY -= 1))` will *always* have a zero exit code so will not exit prematurely.

This exit code behaviour is best seen with:

```
DELAY=10
while [ ${DELAY} -gt 0 ] ; do
    echo Delaying $DELAY

    # Select one of these below, comment the other:
    ((DELAY -= 1))
    #: $((DELAY -= 1))

    echo "   Exit code $?"
done
echo Finishing
```

and changing which line is used to decrements `DELAY`.

Answer (score 0):

If `set -x` is in operation, the sequence of `: 3`, `: 2`, `: 1` will be echoed.

This is a "cheap" way to both decrement and optionally echo the result.

Comment: If `set -x` was active, wouldn't that output be swamped by all the other lines being executed? If all you wanted was a countdown timer, I would have thought `echo $((DELAY -= 1))` would be better, with no need for `set -x`.